# Stripe Connect - URL for onboarding crashes

Tags: node.js, reactjs, stripe-payments

I am building an onboarding flow for new customers on my platform, specifically the sellers right now, and I am running into an error I am unsure about. I have a node backend and a react frontend. I am able to create an account along with an onboarding link. I am in testing mode.

So my next step was to fill out the onboarding document and submit it for verification as if i was a seller. When I reach the final page and click submit my node server crashes with the following error. Am I misunderstanding how this should work? Or is this just success and now it's on me to redirect?

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/Users/mac/Documents/git_projects/client/index.html'
```

**Node.js**

```
app.post("/create-account-hosted", async (req, res) => {
    const data = req.body;
    try {
        // Create account
        var account = await stripe.accounts.create({
            country: 'US',
            type: 'custom',
            business_type: 'individual',
            capabilities: { card_payments: { requested: true }, transfers: { requested: true }, }
            //requested_capabilities: ['card_payments', 'transfers'],


        });
        console.log('My Created Account..', account);

        // Create accountLink
        var accountLink = await stripe.accountLinks.create({
            account: account.id,
            success_url: 'http://localhost:4242?success',
            failure_url: 'http://localhost:4242?failure',
            type: 'custom_account_verification',
            collect: 'eventually_due'
        });

        console.log('Account link info...', accountLink)

    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(400)
        res.send({ error: err })
        return;
    }
    res.send([accountLink, { "account_id": account.id }]);
});
```

Below are the pics of where I end up and at what part:

[image]

And then this happens:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Am I misunderstanding how this should work? Or is this just success and now it's on me to redirect?

The latter. You've successfully created the account link when you called the `create()`

```
var accountLink = await stripe.accountLinks.create({
            account: account.id,
            success_url: 'http://localhost:4242?success',
            failure_url: 'http://localhost:4242?failure',
            type: 'custom_account_verification',
            collect: 'eventually_due'
        });
```

The `success_url` would be a page on your site you'd want to redirect the user to. Same for the `failure_url`.

If you dig into the [stripe docs](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/integration-builder) we can see an example of their `success.html` page and it's just a sample dummy page users are sent to on payment success in this example.

success.html:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Thanks for your order!</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <section>
    <p>
      We appreciate your business! If you have any questions, please email
      <a href="mailto:orders@example.com">orders@example.com</a>.
    </p>
  </section>
</body>
</html>
```

This again confirms that you can redirect to any page you want on success. Hope that helped!

Comment: Thank you, this was perfect guidance. Appreciate the help!